# Debug another selector while single stepping in Xcode using lldb

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, lldb

I am in my code stopped at a breakpoint at the (lldb) prompt.  I can message objects and get their value printed on the console.

```
(lldb) p [self computePI]
(float) $1 = 3.0
```

Whoa!  Something is wrong at this point.  I would like to be able to step into computePI as a shortcut to figuring out which variables are messed up.  However, if I put a breakpoint on that selector and try again I get:

```
(lldb) p [self computePI]
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: breakpoint 5.1.
The process has been returned to the state before execution.
```

It would be a real time saver if I could somehow step into computePI at this point.  Is this possible or not?  I have been looking at http://lldb.llvm.org and haven't seen anything.  Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE:**  Based on Jason Molenda's answer I updated my ~/.lldbinit file with the following handy aliases:

```
command alias nup expr -u 0 -- 
command alias nupo expr -u 0 -o --
```

That lets me use nup (in place of p) and nupo (in place of po).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `p` command is really an alias to `expr --`.  One of the options to `expr` is `-u` or `--unwind-on-error` -- in this case a breakpoint is treated as an "error" (which might be considered a bug in and of itself - it's debatable, there are use cases where it would be nonintuitive for this to behave differently.)

Anyway, you should be able to do

```
(lldb) expr -u false -- [self computePI]
```

and it will stop at the breakpoint.  The `--` here indicates to `expr` that it should stop doing option parsing and everything after that is an expression to evaluate.